# Multiple Match bindings found on line with two different parameters

Tags: c#, .net, bdd, specflow, feature-file

I have written two lines(When's) in my same feature file

```
When user $action1$ $key1$ with $value1$ for $atttributeType_Value$ in $Filename1_SectionId1$
Then abc
When user $action2$ $key2$ with $value2$ in $Filename2_SectionId2$
Then def
```

and corresponding step definition in step definition file

as

```
[When(@"user (.*) (.*) with (.*) for (.*) in (.*)")]
public void abc()
{   //operation }

[When(@"user (.*) (.*) with (.*) in (.*)")]
public void def()
{   //operation }
```

But, its showing up an error as "Multiple match bindings found. Navigating to first match.."

When I try to navigate for 1st line its giving error... But when I navigate using second When line. it's navigating properly.

I have used "$" at the place where "<" and ">" should be there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your second regex:

```
with (.*) in (.*)
```

matches both these lines

```
with a partridge in a pear tree
with a partridge for Christmas in a pear tree
```

In the first instance, it'll pick up "partridge" and "a pear tree" as the two arguments. In the second, it will pick up "partridge for Christmas" and "a pear tree" as the arguments. Since your first regex also matches that second line, it is indeed finding multiple bindings.

You could use a different regex. For instance, if you want to pick out a whole word and not have any whitespace included, try `(\S*)` instead of `(.*)`. That `.` matches anything, including spaces. More on regex [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @@lunivore. Thanks for helping with regex.  It's working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the Visual Studio integration jumps to the first step definition it finds.

The Regex of the def()- Steps catches also the cases of the abc- Step.
Did you tried to put the parameters within single quotes?

Like that:

Feature:

```
When user '$action1$' '$key1$' with '$value1$' for '$atttributeType_Value$' in   '$Filename1_SectionId1$'
Then abc
When user '$action2$' '$key2$' with '$value2$' in '$Filename2_SectionId2$'
Then def
```

Step Bindings:

```
[When(@"user '(.*)' '(.*)' with '(.*)' for '(.*)' in '(.*)'")]
public void abc()
{   //operation }

[When(@"user '(.*)' '(.*)' with '(.*)' in '(.*)'")]
public void def()
{   //operation }
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: I tried with single quotes also..but it's not working